# How do I share models using a library that should be directly extended upon in a binary with Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I want to be able to share the data structures (models) in the code base for the service I am building.
I have currently split up the code in a library named `domain` and a binary named `log_service`.

In the `domain` library I have defined a structure that will contain the information for a Log as shown below.

```
pub struct Log {
    pub id: u32,
    pub message: String,
}
```

In the `log_service` binary I want to use diesel as a database ORM and use this structure defined in the `domain` library as a table. The diesel documentation states that in order to use this structure as a database table, you need to derive certain traits (e.g. `Queryable`) and possibly apply other attributes.

However Rust does not allow extension of this struct from within another crate, and because inheritance does not exist in Rust, there is usually the option of using composition to wrap the `domain` Log. But because diesel uses the struct to directly map to a table, it's not possible to use composition to expose the fields, because they should be top level on the struct.

Preferably I wouldn't want to copy paste this struct in both crates.
I've been thinking of using a macro to  generate these structures in both code bases from a single source, which would still allow extending the Log in the binary.

What would be the optimal way to solve this?

Comment: Why is it necessary to define it in `domain` instead of `log_service`, where you could directly derive what you need?

Comment: @LotB I need to share these structures between multiple services without copy-pasting their definition, as they will be making use of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This can't be (easily) done if you absolutely have to maintain the current structure of your project.

Rust's [`orphan rules`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/implementations.html#trait-implementation-coherence) states:

> ... that every trait implementation must meet either of the following conditions:
>
> 1. The trait being implemented is defined in the same crate.
> 2. At least one of either Self or a generic type parameter of the trait must meet the following grammar, where C is a nominal type defined within the containing crate:
>
> ```
>  T = C
>    | &C
>    | &mut C
>    | Box<C>
> ```

Simply put, either the trait or the struct has to be local to the crate in order for you to implement it.

So the easiest option for you would be to derive [`diesel::deserialize::Queryable`](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.3/diesel/deserialize/trait.Queryable.html) for your `Log` struct in `domain` crate itself.